# Reset current Stack in TabNavigator and navigate to other Stack (react-navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have my two stack navigators defined as below.

```
const Stack1 = createStackNavigator({
    Step1, // screen
    Step2, // screen
    Step3  // screen
});

const Stack2 = createStackNavigator({
    First,  // screen
    Second  // screen
});
```

And the Tab Navigator:

```
const AppStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Stack1,
    Stack2,
    Stack3,
    Stack4
});
```

When the user is in the Step3 screen (from Stack1) and presses a button I want to : 
 
1. Reset Stack1 and Stack2, without reseting Stack3 and Stack4 
2. Then navigate to a certain screen in Stack2 (ex. 'First' screen).

Anyone know how to achieve this in the simplest and most efficient fashion?

My current workaround, which only resets Stack2 and navigates to the First screen:

```
navigation.dispatch(
    StackActions.push({
        routeName: 'Stack2',
        action: StackActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          key: null,
          actions: [
            StackActions.push({ routeName: 'First' }),
          ],
        }),
    })
);
```

Version:
"react-navigation": "~2.3.1"

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  I'm trying to do something similar and it would be great to hear how you solved it!